# Get containing object

Tags: php

I have two classes

```
class Table {
    public $rows = array();
    public $name;

    public function __construct($name, $rows) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->rows = $rows;
    }
}

class Row {
    public $name;

        public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create an object table and add 2 rows to it.

```
$rows = array(
    new Row("Row 1"),
    new Row("Row 2")
);
$table = new Table("Table 1", $rows);
```

So far so good.. 
But is there a possibility to get the containing table of a row?
For example:

```
foreach($table->rows AS $row) {
    echo $row->name . ' is member of table ' . $row->getContainingTable()->name;
}
```

This is only an example...

Comment: Public variables are a bad idea, they break encapsulation.

Comment: I know, but this is only a sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to change your `Row` class (pass the `Table` object to it):

```
class Row {
    public $name;
    protected $table;

    public function __construct($name, Table $table) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function getContainingTable(){ 
      return $this->table;
    }
}
```

If you cannot do that on instantiation, create a setter method and use it after you pass the rows to the table :)

Actually, here's a better idea:

```
class Table {
    public $rows = array();
    public $name;

    public function __construct($name, array $rows) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->rows = $rows;

        foreach($rows as $row)
          $row->setContainingTable($this);
    }
}

class Row {
    public $name;
    protected $table;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setContainingTable(Table $table){ 
      $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function getContainingTable(){ 
      return $this->table;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your class structure to something like this

```
<?php
class MyCollection implements IteratorAggregate
{
    private $items = array();
    private $count = 0;

    // Required definition of interface IteratorAggregate
    public function getIterator() {
        return new MyIterator($this->items);
    }

    public function add($value) {
        $this->items[$this->count++] = $value;
   }
}

$coll = new MyCollection();
$coll->add('value 1');
$coll->add('value 2');
$coll->add('value 3');

foreach ($coll as $key => $val) {
    echo "key/value: [$key -> $val]\n\n";
}
?>
```

have a look at [iterators in php 5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php) and see the examples this example is from there to